# Dynamically change database due to WHERE MySQL Crystal Reports

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I'm programming with .NET 4.5, VS 2012 with CrystalReports in and MySQL (the last ^^).

I have 3 or more tables named like "rp31_bla_***2012***_bla" or "rp31_bla_***2013***_bla" or ...

*Imagine* you have a table with this:

**- Name   - Age - Job      - Year -**

- Robert - 45  - Doctor   - 2001
- Robert - 45  - Housemade- 2002
- Robert - 45  - Geek     - 2006
- Robert - 45  - Cooker   - 2009
- Robert - 45  - (null)   - 2013
- Nadège - 21  - CallGirl - 2001
- Nadège - 21  - (null)   - 2002
- Nadège - 21  - CallGirl - 2008
- Nadège - 21  - Home     - 2008

Now I have a WinForm with two textBox, if the user writes "Robert" and "2013" I have to make a report with the `"rp31_bla_***2013***_bla" WHERE Name = Robert`. 
Is it possible?
Which type of report should I create?
How can I change dynamically the query?

Comment: If all the yearly data tables are the same, you either need to copy the structure of one of them to make your own datatable to which the report is bound and you fill via your WinForm code behind OR create a datatable that will contain only the information you need for the report to which the report is bound and you fill it via your WinForm code behind. Do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: Hi Ally, thanks for your answer !

Yep I understand what you're saying but, I can have like 5 tables (2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013) of 5000 lines and 10 columns, so I think that if the user wants to take informations from all these tables, it will be really slow to copy what I need in an other table, no ?

If we read the Lan's answer, he proposes a solution and I don't know which one is the faster =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use union to combine the 3 tables and filter by name

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ..., 2012 as Year FROM rp31_bla_2012_bla
UNION 
SELECT ..., 2013 as Year FROM rp31_bla_2013_bla
UNION 
SELECT ..., 2014 as Year FROM rp31_bla_2014_bla
) t 
WHERE t.Year =2013 and t.Name ='Robert'

Since the datasource will never change you don't need to to switch the tables.
This approach will be slower because you will always query the 3 tables

Another option will be to use a command in Crystal reports and to create a dynamic query which will be executed using exec -then you will be able to query just one table but you will need to handle special characters in the name ( like '%?)

Comment: Hi Lan, thanks too for your answer.

I understand what you're saying, but I'll not always query the 3 tables (even if I want only 1 or 2 of them).

I can do something like that:

List<string> yearTable = the years the user wrotes;

foreach (String year in yearTable)
    {
        And here I construct the query with all the dates I want, and         in all the files I want =)
    }

But what is the faster option ? Ally solution or yours ? :)